# Azure ARM error "ResourceReferenceUsesWrongSubscriptionId"

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to deploy a Application Gateway that has a reference to a subnet which is residing in a different subscription than where I want deploy the Application Gateway.

The deployment script looks something like this (rest of file omitted to reduce complexity):

Variable:

```json
"variables": {
    "virtualNetworksExternalId": "[resourceId('<another-subscription-id>','<resource-group-name>','Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', '<resource-name>', '<subnet-name>')]"
},
```

Gateway ressource

```json
{
    "type": "Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways",
    "apiVersion": "2020-05-01",
    "name": "[parameters('applicationGatewayName')]",
    "location": "westeurope",
    "properties": {
        "gatewayIPConfigurations": [
            {
                "name": "appGatewayIpConfig",
                "properties": {
                    "subnet": {
                        "id": "[variables('virtualNetworksExternalId')]"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

However, when I deploy the template, I get the following error from Azure:

```
Exception Details:
Error Code: ResourceReferenceUsesWrongSubscriptionId
Message: Property subnet of resource /subscriptions/<current-subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<name-of-rg>/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/<name-of-appliationgateway> can only reference resources in subscription(s) <current-subscription-id>. Value /subscriptions/<another-subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<name-of-network>/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/<name-of-net>/subnets/<name-of-subnet> references wrong subscription.
```

Is it not possible to reference a resource from another subscription via ARM or am I doing something else wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the use of ARM template but how application gateway works.

"Application Gateway is a dedicated deployment in your virtual network." Therefore, it cannot be used cross subscriptions.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-faq